# Use desktop speakers over SSH from laptop

Tags: ssh, centos, x11, vlc

I have VLC media player and media files on a desktop CentOS 6.3 set up (without a GUI). I can play the media files at the machine but when I issue the command via SSH it is silent. I'm guessing it's because there is peripheral confusion when using SSH.

I looked into X11 forwarding but I must not be understanding it correctly because it still doesn't work. I'm starting to think that's for GUI purposes and not CLI.

How can I SSH to my desktop and use the peripherals of the desktop when I issue the commands remotely?

Comment: Pulseaudio can route audio over the network. http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/pulseaudio I had it working many-many moons ago, but I changed hardware and it is no longer required for myself. I know it exists, I don't know how to implement it. Hence a link that I think is useful in a comment, rather than a full blown answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realized it was working for **root only**. Running it as a normal user in VLC's ncurses interface i typed `L` and seen error messages about permissions:

```
[alsa] cannot open ALSA device "default": Permission denied
[main] Audio output failed
[main] The audio device "default" could not be used:
[jack] failed to connect to JACK server
[main] no suitable audio output module
[main] failed to create audio output
```

After some Googling i seen people were saying add the user to the `audio` group. I did:

`cat /etc/group |cut -d: -f1` and verified that i did indeed have an audio group already.

So i did this:

`usermod -a -G audio marshall` which added my user "marshall" to the audio group.

Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

A good alternative that I actually use a lot to control the music on my computer from another device on the same network (even my phone over wifi), is the VLC web interface, as nicely explained on this [entry on the vlc wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_via_a_browser) and [also here](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aModules/http_intf#VLC_2.0.0_and_later).

```
vlc -I http
```

To access it, on a web browser you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Instead of 127.0.0.1 you need to type the ip of the server.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that on the server you need to edit the vlc `.hosts` file to allow other devices to access the web interface. Otherwise, VLC only allows local connections. The file should be at `/usr/share/vlc/lua/http/.hosts`, at the end you need to add the ips of the devices you want to have access from.

Comment: Actually, i have the music and sound system on the server. My question is how can i start the music over ssh with my laptop and have it play on the sound system that is hooked up to the server?

Comment: Yeah I was unsure of that. I'll delete this and post another one. I think I know how. ANd may not even need to use ssh.

Comment: Weird, it is working after installing `screen` but i'm not actually using screen...

Comment: the only other difference is that i had logged out of the actual server so that the only user logged in was the ssh session on my laptop.

Comment: but yeah, over an open ssh session, it should work without problems.

Comment: The actual problem was that i was on as a regular user, when i play the song over ssh as root it works. What gives?

Comment: @MarshallHouse: is your non-root user a member of the  `audio` group or similar? Try `ls -l /dev/dsp` to see which group you need to be member of to have write access.

Comment: cannot access /dev/dsp: No such file or directory